# Parameterized Queries

Tags: php, mysql, parameterized-query

I am currently learning parametrized queries as there are advantages to using them.

Could someone give some pointers by converting this block of code to a parametrized version?

Thanks.

```
if(isset($_GET['news_art_id']) && (!empty($_GET['news_art_id'])))
{
    $news_art_id = htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['news_art_id']));
    $news_art_id = validate_intval($news_art_id);

    //echo $news_art_id;
    $_SESSION['news_art_id'] = $news_art_id;

    // Assign value to status.
    $onstatus = 1;
    settype($onstatus, 'integer');

    $query = 'SELECT M.id, M.j_surname, M.j_points_count, M.j_level, A.j_user_id,A.id, A.jart_title, A.jart_tags, A.jart_description, A.jart_createddate FROM jt_articles A, jt_members M WHERE M.id = A.j_user_id AND A.id = ' . check_db_query_id($news_art_id) . " AND A.jart_status = $onstatus;";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Something went wrong. ' . mysql_error());  
    $artrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using htmlentities(), strip_tags(), and your "validate_intval()" function, why not just do: $news_art_id = (int)$_GET['news_art_id']; (int) will transform any non-integer value into "0" (which is usually not a valid i.d. and will match nothing in your db). No chance of SQL injection that way and it uses a lot less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case there is no advantage, remember a parameterised query requires 2 calls to the db : one to setup the query template and parse, the other to populate the query template params and is typically used when looping. So in this instance you're better off calling a stored procedure (always the best choice) or using inline sql and making sure you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php when applicable.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule is: Every variable should be binded, no inline variables at all.

Technical details: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: A real life example using the above code block will really go a long way in explaining to some of us learning how to implement it. For example how one gat variables from form values?? Thanx

Comment: @Frank Nwoko: please, read that article and **try** to do it yourself. After that, if you'll experience some issues - come back here and ask some specific question. That is the correct way to learn.