# How to safely insert code in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website where users can store code snippets, using PHP and a mySQL database. But I can't figure out how to safely insert user inputed code into my database. I can't transform the input with the 'safety' functions I normally use (`trim`, `stripslashes`, etc.) because the whole point is that you can view the code as it's inputed in the database. I've looked at `my_real_escape_string()` but I saw that it does not escape the `%` and `_`, which can be used as MySQL wildcards. Does that pose a threat, or can I just use `my_real_escape_string`? Thanx in advance.

Comment: [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/addcslashes) is commonly used in addition to normal escaping or parameter binding to mask placeholders for `LIKE` expressions.

Comment: previous StackOverFlow Questions that could answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461759/parameterized-queries

Comment: trim/stripslashes are NOT safety functions. Extra space is never a concern in sql, unless you're worried about losing data in a fixed-length text/string field. stripslashes is a moronic braindead piece of garbage leftover from PHP's earlier days when magic_quotes was king of the land.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wildcards only take effect when used in `SELECT` queries and then only when using certain functions. So for inserting the code it will be fine to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` as they will have no effect.

To make it better I would recommend that you use [PHPs PDO](http://php.net/pdo) so that you can use parameter binding. The following example is from [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `mysql_real_escape_string()` provides complete protection for string values. The fact that there may be `%` and `_` in the data is not relevant, they do not pose a security threat.

For int values, you need to either validate whether they actually are numbers, or wrap them into quotes:

```
$intValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["intValue"]);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET intValue ='$intValue'"); 
                                                        // note the quotes
```

Without the quotes, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is useless on numeric values!

However, as @Daniel A. White already said, if you are just starting out, consider using the [PDO library](http://php.net/pdo) instead. It's newer than the old mySQL functions and offers parametrized queries that, if used properly, make SQL injection impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameterized insert statement. Actually, use parameterized even for your selects and updates.

it will automatically handle these things for you.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's arguably not really an answer to the OP's question. Plus you're not explaining which library to use

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO fruit(name, colour, calories) VALUES(?, ?);');
$sth->execute(Array($calories, $colour));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me, [adscript] is a code snippet.

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="80"><input name="adscript" type="text/javascript" class="text-input textarea" id="adscript"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['adscript']);?>" size="80" height="40" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
```